# Application Insights: Adding cloud role name via custom ITelemetryInitializer in .net core 3.1 console app does not pick up the cloud role name

Tags: .net-core, console-application, azure-application-insights, nlog, .net-core-3.1

I'm using HostBuilder to configure the console app in Program.cs.

In `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomInitializer>(p => new CustomInitializer("my app", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));

services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
```

in `ConfigureLogging`:

```cs
logging.ClearProviders();
logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
logging.AddNLog(NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration("nlog.config").Configuration);
logging.AddApplicationInsights();
```

in `CustomInitializer.cs`:

```cs
class CustomInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private readonly string _roleName;
    private readonly string _roleInstance;

    public CloudRoleNameInitializer(string name, string instance)
    {
        _roleName = name;
        _roleInstance = instance;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = _roleName;
        telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = _roleInstance;
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using nlog as well. When I log my messages I can see that the cloud role name isn't set to "my app" instead is set to my computer name. I experimented with a few possibilities in the `ConfigureServices` section:

### Trial 1:

```cs
services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>((config) =>
        {
            config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new CustomInitializer("my app", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
        });
```

This didn't work.

### Trial 2

```cs
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new CustomInitializer("my app", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
```

This worked very well but I kept getting the IDE warning that this was now obsolete in .net core

I've checked all the documentation there is nothing which gives me a good idea on a substitute for using `TelemetryConfiguration.Active`. It seems most examples are geared toward .net core web apps and not console.

Comment: Did you try to swap the order of `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService` and `services.AddSingleton` ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue; I tried swapping the order and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

NLog seems like using the TelemetryConfiguration.Active for creation of the TelemetryClient so all ITelemetryInitializer are getting ignored.

My solution for this was to add following setting for application insights

```json
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "xxx",
    "EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup": true 
},
```

It seems that EnableActiveTelemetryConfigurationSetup == true automatically propagates telemetry settings from ServiceCollection into TelemetryConfiguration.Active.